# Изменение новостей из MySQL с помощью php

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Я решил в админке сделать изменение новостей, написал вот такой скрипт, но я не знаю что написать в этой строке **$results = mysql_query("UPDATE //что тут то?//");**
Помогите, пожалуйста. 
Структура таблицы news http://prntscr.com/2ix0be
Дамп:

```
     CREATE TABLE `news` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
          `body` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
          `putdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
          `hide` enum('show','hide') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'show',
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Скрипт

```
<?php 
    $host='localgost';
    $name='name';
    $user='user';
    $pass='pass';
    mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `news` FROM news2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");

    while($record=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    echo $record['id']; 
    echo '<textarea>'.$record['news'].'</textarea>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="изменить" />';
    echo '<br>'; }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $results = mysql_query("UPDATE //что тут то?//");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Вы нам структуру таблицы **news** покажете или нам самим угадывать?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2ix0be

Comment: а может вы бы по почте ещё структуру таблицы выслали на дощечке вырезанную ? дамп схемы давайте. Со скриншотами работать неудобно. Очень всем было бы удобно если бы вы показали это на sqlfiddle.

Comment: и  вот ещё:

[deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Дамп я добавил в текст. Посмотрите выше.
Хостинг: PHP Версия: 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update news set body = 'тут новый текст новости' where id = 'тут номер изменяемой новости'
```

Comment: Мне надо вписать что то в этот скрипт, я не знаю ксожелению что :c
`$results = mysql_query("UPDATE //что тут то?//");`

Answer (score 1):

Посмотреть рабочий пример на **[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b226c/1)**

**Пример таблицы до запроса:**

```
+--+------+----------------------+------------------------------+----+
|id|name  |body                  |putdate                       |hide|
+--+------+----------------------+------------------------------+----+
|3 |Test A|Simple text version A |January, 13 2014 10:03:00+0000|hide|
|4 |Test B|Simple text version B |January, 13 2014 10:03:00+0000|hide|
|5 |Test C|Simple text version C |January, 13 2014 10:03:00+0000|hide|
+--+------+----------------------+------------------------------+----+
```

**Пример запроса:**

```
UPDATE `news`
SET `body` = 'Welcome to the future!'
WHERE `id` = 5;
```

**Пример таблицы после запроса:**

```
+--+------+----------------------+------------------------------+----+
|id|name  |body                  |putdate                       |hide|
+--+------+----------------------+------------------------------+----+
|3 |Test A|Simple text version A |January, 13 2014 10:03:00+0000|hide|
|4 |Test B|Simple text version B |January, 13 2014 10:03:00+0000|hide|
|5 |Test C|Welcome to the future!|January, 13 2014 10:03:00+0000|hide|
+--+------+----------------------+------------------------------+----+
```